# Condition for CP violation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, cp-violation

I am studying how weak and strong phases lead to CP violation. I am following CP Violation by Branco. There is some algebra that I can not follow.

Consider the process :  $ a + \bar{a} \rightarrow b +  c $ . The book says that the quantity which violates CP is 
$$ \left<c|T|a\right>\left<b|T|\bar{a}\right>-n_{b}n_{c} \left< b|T|a\right>\left<c|T|\bar{a}\right>$$
where $n_{b} $ and  $n_{c}$ are eigenvalues of CP for $b$ and $c$ respectively, and $T$ is the transition matrix.

Now, the transition amplitude for the given process (to my understanding) should be given by $ \left< b c|T | a \bar{a}\right> $. The quantity defined in book compares two cases,

1. $a$ is going to $b$ and $\bar{a}$ is going to $c$
2. $a$ is going to $c$ and $\bar{a}$ is going to $b$.

Please explain why can we write transition probilities like this and what does this CP violating quantity actually is.

Comment: If you mean the paragraph 5.1 of the Branco, it's never stated that $\langle bc |T|a\bar{a} \rangle = \langle b |T|\bar{a} \rangle \langle c |T|a\rangle $, he is simultaneously considering the processes $\langle c |T|\bar{a} \rangle$, $\langle c |T|a\rangle$, $\langle b |T|\bar{a} \rangle$ and $\langle b |T|a \rangle$ and he's applying CP. Try to read it with more attention.

Comment: @Karozo Thank you for having a look at the document. I am not saying that $\left< bc|T|a \bar{a} \right> = \left<b|T|\bar{a} \right> \left<c|T|a \right> $ . Read my question again. I don't understand how this quantity (mentioned in question) is a non zero number when CP is violated.

Comment: I think that this is what you want: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle c|T| a \rangle  & \langle b|T|\bar{a} \rangle =  \\ \langle c|(CP)^{\dagger}(CP)T (CP)^{\dagger}(CP)|a \rangle & \langle b|(CP)^{\dagger}(CP)T(CP)^{\dagger}(CP)| \bar{a} \rangle = \\ n_b n_c \langle c|T| \bar{a} \rangle & \langle b | T | a \rangle 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
 Where I have used $(CP)T(CP)^{\dagger}=T$, if the difference between that two quantities is different from zero it means that something is wrong, for example the states aren't eigenstates of $CP$ or the transition matrix $T$ is not CP-invariant.